# UIRecorder in Instruments - IPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, instruments

HI,
     Using UIRecorder in Instruments comes with IPhone SDK, how to play recorded actions stored as .trace files.Please let me know..!

Thanks
Nagaraj

Answer (score 0):

Hey.
Record in instruments means recording some statistics (defined by given instruments in Instruments), not recording actions you perform on app. Actually You need to perform actions on iPhone or provide JavaScript (that is using UIAutomation api) that will do actions on your app.